# Python Multiprocessing: worker pool vs process

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a discord bot I need to scale.
The main features of the bot is to fetch data from a 3rd party website and also keep a database with member info.
These 2 operations are quite time consuming and I wanted to have a separate worker/process for each of them.

My constraints:

- There is a limit of GET's per min with the 3rd party website.
- The database can't be accessed simultaneously for same guild.

I've been researching online for the best way to do this but I come into several libraries/ways to implement this kind of solution. What are the options I have and their strengths and weaknesses?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a limit on the amount of requests from the host, I would first try to run a synchronous program and check whether the limit is reached before the minute ends. If it does then there would be no need to concurrently run other workers. However if the limit is not reached, then I would recommend you use both `asyncio` and `aiohttp` to asynchronously get the requests. There's a ton of information out there on how to get started using these libraries.

The other option would be to use the good old `threading` module (or `concurrent.futures` for a higher level use case). Both options have their pros and cons. What I would do is first try the `concurrent.futures` (namely, the `ThreadPoolExecutor` context manager) module since you only have to add like one line of code. If it does not get the job done, then remember: use `asyncio` if you have to, and `threading` if you must. Both of these modules are easy to use and understand as well, but they do need to follow a general structure, which means you'll most likely have to change your code.

Comment: The limit is easily reached at 120 requests per min but I could increase that by getting more access tokens. I already use asyncio and aiohttp to get the data. At this state the bot can handle all this but since I already takes about 5min to get all the data from the website I think I need to scale it if I want more guilds.